# How to create a regular expression to match the last occurrence of something?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that looks like this:

```
one[two][three][four]
```

I would like to capture the contents of the last bracket, so I tried this:

```
/\[(.*)\]$/
```

However, that returned a result of:

```
two][three][four
```

How can I form the regex to only match the contents of the last brackets?

Comment: I think you need non-greedy matching...

Comment: you dont need regex for this

Comment: @Anirudh, my answer exactly... but PP decided it doesn't answer the question... :)

Comment: @gdoron the op did ask specifically for a regex. Had he asked for "a" solution to find the last occurrence, your answer would have been sufficient

Comment: @Tung, People should really start think out of the box. Other solutions are always valid, unless the OP mentions they are not allowed. My 2 cents.

Comment: Interesting, I just tested `.*(\[.*\])` at http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html and it gave me `[four]` for the group. But that's Java.

Comment: But actually http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/javascript/index.html - also matches [four]

Comment: @OndraŽižka. You have included `[` and `]` inside the capture group.

Comment: I realize there may be other ways to accomplish this, but a regex answer would be nice so I can better understand regular expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using greedy quantifier, that reads everything between first `[` and last `]`. You can use the below regex:

```
/\[([^\]]*)\]$/
```

---

If by some chance, your `]` is not at the end of the string, then you can use add another character class to match any characters but `[` and `]` before the end:

```
/\[([^\]]*)\][^\[\]]*$/
```

---

But, honestly this problem should better be solved using string operation rather than using regex, as in [@gdoron's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17598163/1679863)

Comment: What about the situation where the closing bracket isn't the last thing on the line?

Comment: @PP.. That situation can be handled easily by adding another character class before `$`. I didn't assume this thing though given OP question.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding the question mark did not solve my problem, but your second solution worked perfectly.

Comment: @Andrew. Are you sure `.*?` didn't work? That should work perfectly.

Comment: @Andrew that doesn't capture the content within `[]`!

Comment: Try this in a javascript console: `'one[two][three]'.match(/\[(.*?)\]$/)[1]` and `'one[two][three]'.match(/\[([^\]]*)\]$/)[1]` The second one works while the first does not.

Comment: @Andrew try this one `\b\w+(?=\]$)` or `[^\[]+(?=\]$)` :P..no need of groups..!

Comment: -1 why so many upvotes for wrong ans? 1>1st regex doesnt work 2>2nd one includes `[]`

Comment: @Anirudh. Well, the 2nd one captures the content inside `[]` in 1st capture group. Group 0 will give the complete match.

Comment: @Anirudh. That's what surprises me. I don't understand how `.*?` is not behaving reluctantly. For now, removed that regex.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, for your case you don't even need regex:

```
var str = 'one[two][three][four]';
alert(str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('[') +1, str.lastIndexOf(']')));
```

It get the substring between the last `[` and `]`

Comment: Didn't even attempt to answer the question.

Comment: @PP. I see, answer a question means: your solution with your nickname on the right. good to know.

Comment: I'll give you a +1 for providing an alternate solution, but I agree that is doesn't answer the question of how to fix the regex.

Answer (score 1):

Regex search starts from left to right..Hence it matches `two][three][four`..This wont work even if you use `.*?`

You should use this regex

```
[^\[]+(?=\]$)
```

---

But I would prefer this

```
var output=input.substring(input.lastIndexOf("[")+1,input.lastIndexOf("]"));
```

Comment: The last part is now good, but the regex returns `[four]`... Sorry for annoying that much. :)

Comment: @gdoron problem is that regex in javascript doesn't support lookbehind..but there's a workaround you can use this regex `\b\w+(?=\]$)`

Answer (score 1):

I have tested

`.*(\[.*\])` at [RegexPlanet](http://regexplanet.com/advanced/javascript/index.html) and it gave me [four] for the group 1.

People are talking about *greedy*, note that there are also *possessive* quantifiers, like `.*+` which is "even more greedy" and may be useful sometimes.

PS: I got a good lesson of regular expressions from the [JTexy project](http://code.google.com/p/jtexy/) - see [here](http://code.google.com/p/jtexy/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fcore%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fresources%2Fcz%2Fdynawest%2Fjtexy%2Fmodules). It's Java, but uses PCRE.

Answer (score 0):

Greedy expressions are your friend. They will attempt to get everything they can... then backtrack when they can't.

To this end you can prepend most expressions with `^.*` which will try and match as much as possible from the beginning.. leaving the end to whatever you want to find.

So if you want to capture just the end... try:

```
^.*\[(.*?)\]
```

Let's break this down:

```
^          # start of string
.*         # as much as possible
\[         # opening square bracket
(.*?)      # capture the minimum possible (non-greedy)
\]         # closing square bracket
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

`\[[^\[]*$`
? This matches a '[' that has no other '['s after it, and returns anything after.